# How to (visual studio 2008 / Resharper) refactor / automate mixin pattern

Tags: visual-studio-2008, refactoring, resharper

I have Visual Studio 2008 with Resharper, does anyone know if there is any refactorings available that let you say create a class and use a member variable as a mixin?

As a basic example, alot of the time you might want to implement a particular interface and use 95% of the underlying code of an already existing object (such as a list), is there any way to easily hook up those methods automatically?  (Assume the class i want to use functionality from is SEALED and inheriting from it and overriding methods is not an option.

```
class CustomList : IList<string>
{
    List<string> m_list

    void Add(string val){  m_list.Add(val) }
    void Delete(string val){  m_list.Delete(val) }
    ....etc
}
```

Comment: This is a sort of Extract Decorator type pattern isn't it?

Comment: I believe its just considered either composition or more commonly known as a mixin.  The pattern itself is not the issue, its automatically re-wiring the internal objects methods directly to the composing objects interface.

Comment: Yes, it's also known as `Decorator` design pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it via the <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Insert</kbd> (Generate Code) shortcut key. Select **Delegating Members** in the popup, and it will open a dialog in which you can select the methods you want.

Make sure you do this before selecting "Implement Interface", or else you'll end up with duplicate methods, and thus a compilation error.

[image]

Comment: Excellent! I was able to use this info along with http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Generation__Delegating_Members.html in order to generate an adapter to a static class!